# Remove web / app.php of reference. Symfony2

Tags: symfony

All requests go through the file web / app.php (similar to index.php), such as a request to the main page - adwords-up.com/web/app.php, input - adwords-up.com /web/app.php/login. I want part of the web / app.php removed from the link. In the configuration .htaccess, redirect to the default web / app.php, so that a request for such was the main form - http://adwords-up.com/, and Page login - http://adwords-up.com/login.

There is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/adwords-up.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName adwords-up

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/adwords-up/web
# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On 
    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable. 
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the 
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper 
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will 
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size 
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment 
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead. 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1] 

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content 
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial 
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an 
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller -> 
    # redirect -> request -> ...). 
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected 
    # to the startpage because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS 
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices: 
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or 
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the 
    # following RewriteCond (best solution) 
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ 
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L] 

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it. 
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories. 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
    RewriteRule .? - [L] 
    </IfModule>
```

add this to your .htaccess and be sure to have rewriteEngine activated
also this is a common question with answers even on the symfon2 doc

Comment: do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in apache?

Comment: Yes.                                             `exit(var_dump(in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())));`   boolean true

Comment: put it in the .htaccess located in the /web dir

Comment: Yes, I put there (web/.htaccess). But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up apache virtual host and put the correct document root and rewrite rules.
example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName adwords-up.com
    DocumentRoot <path-to-your-codebase>/web
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteRule ^/app.php/(.*) http://adwords-up.com/$1
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /app.php/$1 [QSA,L]

    <Directory "<path-to-your-codebase>/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it helps